# latin small letter acute in SCSS

Tags: css, unicode, sass

I've been trying to use this letter in a mixin.

```
@mixin btn($text, $color) {
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover {
        .text {
            &::after {
                content: $text;
            }
        }
    }
}

.btnbitacora {
    @include btn("Bit\0000E1cora", #00b8d4);
}
```

But in browser shows:

"Bitá cora", splitted, and i need "Bitácora".

I put all bunch of 0 because if i put it without them it shows me a wierd symbol (ฟ)

When i was looking for information about this topic i found this site (https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) i don't know from who is this site but when i write the same word, it showed scaped in this same way:

"Bit\00E1 cora"

I would really appreaciate some help about this.

**Updated:**

I think something wierd is happening with my project, because a i did try those solutions on a codepen and works fine, i even try the same solution on a external project and did work.

So i am wondering, What's going on?

This is my package.json

```
   devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@prettier/plugin-php": "^0.14.0",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1",
        "bulma": "^0.8.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "prettier": "^2.0.4",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "ts-loader": "^8.0.1",
        "typescript": "^4.1.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
        "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.10",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
        "@types/react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.3",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0"
    }
```

Comment: You should put a space after E1. `\E1`, `\00E1`, and `\0000E1` are all the same. Just if you write `\00E1cora` it will be read as `\00E1C ora` (C is an hexadecimal number).

Comment: BTW: why not print the character somewhere and put it into the string without escaping. Modern (and less modern) browsers support UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

From [official documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/strings):

> When an unquoted string is parsed, the literal text of escapes are parsed as part of the string. For example, \a is parsed as the characters , a, and space. In order to ensure that unquoted strings that have the same meanings in CSS are parsed the same way, though, these escapes are normalized. For each code point, whether it’s escaped or unescaped:
>
> - If it’s a valid identifier character, it’s included unescaped in the unquoted string. For example, \1F46D returns the unquoted string .
> - If it’s a printable character other than a newline or a tab, it’s included after a . For example, \21 returns the unquoted string !.
> - **Otherwise, the lowercase Unicode escape is included with a trailing space. For example, \7Fx returns the unquoted string \7f x.**

So

```
@include btn("Bit\E1 cora", #00b8d4);
```

would work fine and produce

```css
.btnbitacora:hover .text::after {
    content: "Bitácora";
}
```

Comment: But it doesnt T.T || I did try that already, and generates splitted. "Bitá cora"